# jquery ajax success data is returned in xml format

Tags: jquery

```
success: function (iID) {
        $("#sss").html(iID);
        alert(iID);
        returnInfo(iID);
    }
```

This is part of my jq-ajax function: the problem is when i call returnInfo I get an error 
“A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client” 
because the iID that is sent is not an int. #sss.html prints it out as an int, but alert prints it out as an xml file with an int tag with the correct value. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check the server code, it decides what format to return the result.

Comment: The return value is int, but it returns it inside an xml file

Comment: If it's inside an XML file, you have to use DOM functions to get it out. XML doesn't automatically extract values, since it can have arbitrary complexity.

Comment: If you post what the XML looks like, we can show how you process it.